# hide YAxis values in HighChart Solid Gauge

Tags: highcharts, gauge

In the below example, is it possible to "hide" the Y Axis values - for example - do not show the 0 and the 200 (in the left).
Looking for cleaner chart..

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid/dark-unica

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By targeting the yAxis labels via CSS you can do so just fine

CSS:

```
.highcharts-axis-labels.highcharts-yaxis-labels{
    display:none;   
}
```

Or alternatively, via setting the `showFirstLabel` and `showLastLabel` property of the yAxis in the case of the gauge has the same effect.

JS:

```
    yAxis: {
        showFirstLabel:false,
        showLastLabel:false,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        title: {
            text: 'RPM'
        }
    }
```

Here is a demo showing both http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/yra3mex6/
Here are the docs regarding the properties http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.showFirstLabel

Answer (score 3):

The following code will hide the Y-axis labels ([JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/1rvdn6L0/)):

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the 'formatter' as shown below:

```
labels: {
            y: 16,
            formatter: function () {
                if(this.value == 0){
                return '0B'; // your choice of value
              } else {
                return '425B'; // you can pass the empty string
              }
            }
        }
```